# Getting Screenfetch to Run After Clearing Terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, bashrc

I currently have screenfetch setup to run automatically every time I open the terminal. What I'm trying to achieve is having screenfetch run again after using the `clear` command, without having to type `screenfetch` again. Is this possible to do in the `.bashrc` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an alias, like this:

```
alias clear="clear && screenfetch"
```

Run the above line as command. Then type `clear` to test how it works. If it works satisfactorily, append the line to the bottom of `~/.bashrc`, then run `source ~/.bashrc`.

You can add this line to the bottom of `~/.bashrc` by the command:

```
echo -e '\nalias clear="clear && screenfetch"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Where:

- `echo` will print to the stdout the string enclosed with the single quotes. The option `-e` will enable interpretation of backslash escapes, so `\n` will be interpreted as new line.
- `>>` will redirect stdout and will append it to the end of `~/.bashrc`.
- `&&` can be read in this way: *if `clear` is executed successfully then execute `screenfetch`*.

Comment: Happy to help, @PapaShots !